# How to get an alternate separator for brace expansion?

Tags: bash

I find myself often doing silly things like:

```
cmd $( echo foo{1,2,3} | tr ' ' , )
```

when I want to invoke `cmd foo1,foo2,foo3`.  I would like instead to be able to do something along the lines of:

`OFS=, ; cmd foo{1,2,3}`

to force the brace expansion to give me a comma separated list.  Is there any such functionality available?

Comment: If `cmd` is always the same, a function might help.

Comment: Interestingly, the documentation for neither brace expansion nor pathname expansion (to which brace expansion is compared) ever actually *says* what the result is. It just says a "list" of words.

Comment: The closest thing I know of would be a clumsy use of an array. `cmd "$(IFS=,; x=(foo{1,2,3}); printf '%s' "${x[*]}")"`.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think it's possible with a simple variable or setting.

However, you can capture the brace expansion in an array, and then use IFS and parameter substitution to achieve that effect:

```
$ ( a=( foo{1,2,3} ); IFS=,; printf -- "%s\n" "${a[*]}" )
foo1,foo2,foo3
```

There, I'm using a subshell so I don't alter IFS in the current shell.

---

Here's a short 
function that's much tidier:

```
$ join() { local IFS=$1; shift; printf -- "%s\n" "$*"; }
$ join , foo{1,2,3}
foo1,foo2,foo3
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create a function that will echo a comma-separated list of its args:

```
commas() { local IFS=,; echo "$*"; }
```

Then you can use it in your calls to `cmd`:

```
cmd "$(commas foo{1,2,3})"
```

Edit: Note that `echo` is somewhat broken, in that if you pass a single arg that looks like a valid `echo` options (e.g., `-e`, `-n`, etc), `echo` will consume it and interpret it as an option instead of printing it.

```
$ commas -e #prints nothing
$ commas -n #prints nothing
$ commas -e -n
-e,-n
```

The last one works because `"$*"` expands to `-e,-n`, which `echo` sees as a single argument.

And `echo` doesn't respect the `--` argument as an "end of options" indicator like `printf` does. So you may want to use `printf -- "%s\n" "$*"`, as in @glennjackman's answer. Then again, the whole point of the `commas` function is to combine multiple args into a comma-separated list, as a single string. So it's probably unlikely that you'd run into any issues with `echo`. But hey, it only costs you a few more characters to type `printf -- "%s"` instead of `echo`.

Comment: The unquoted command substitution can cause problems, depending on what the arguments to `commas` end up being.

Comment: @Aaron Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: @chepner Well spotted. Thanks.